Archive Fails only when invoking fastlane from Remote Jenkins Server works totally fine when done locally or done from Jenkins Localhost
I am trying to build pipeline for our iOS project using (fastlane + Jenkins). It works totally fine when I am running machine on local host but fails when I connect the same AWS EC2 instance to our Jenkins server.
It's gives a CodeSign error. Btw, for fastlane command gym.
Screenshots

☝️Screenshot of a section which I found in gym log.


☝️Screenshots of Jenkins. At only 2 places it comes Archive Failed. So both the screenshots.

☝️Screenshot of Success. On same machine when I login to the GUI and run the lane manually myself.
Basically I had tried literally everything which is available on fastlane Issues, Online forums and Stack Overflow. Some of them are: -

Nuking the certificates and adding them back again.
Trusting the certificates in Keychain.
Unlocking Keychain by using the following commands: - security set-key-partition-list -S apple: -s -k "password" $login and security -v unlock-keychain -p "password" $login.
Keychain > Keys > Selecting Private Keys used for signing > Right Click on Get Info and then allowing all application access.
Downloading and installing Apple's world wide certificates manually.
Setting all the certificates in Login Keychain to "Always Allow.
Deleting and creating new EC2 instance and tried with local machines as well. Every time I do locally it works but every time I do it from Jenkins Server it fails.

Edits
#1  tried importing the intermediate signing certificate. Not working.

You need to import the four intermediate signing certificate on the remote server.
The one AppleWWDRCA.cer may be recently expired and cannot be used anymore;
this needs to be replaced with AppleWWDRCAG3.cer; also
see Apple PKI.
Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate Expiration

Thanks for the answer.
I tried doing the same already but it didn't worked.
But can you please explain why it works when the build is triggered from Local Jenkins or I run fastlane command from terminal by accessing instance through GUI? If intermediate certificates are the problem?
